# Zooming in UIScrollView with another UIScrollView as the content

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to accomplish a scenario where I can zoom in on a UIScrollView. I've seen around that the best way to accomplish this is to have an all-encompassing scrollView, which supports scrolling, and having the other UIScrollViewView inside (instead of the normal application of having a UIImageView inside)

Here's what I have:

```
class Editor: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let menuHeight = CGFloat(60)
    var editor: LevelScrollView? = nil
    var scrollProxy = UIScrollView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let contentFrame = CGRectMake(0,menuHeight,self.view.frame.width,self.view.frame.height-menuHeight)
        scrollProxy.delegate = self
        scrollProxy.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        scrollProxy.frame = contentFrame
        scrollProxy.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollProxy.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollProxy.bounces = false 

        let editor = LevelScrollView(reference: scrollProxy)
        self.editor = editor
        scrollProxy.addSubview(editor)

        scrollProxy.contentSize = self.editor!.contentSize
        scrollProxy.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollProxy.zoomScale = scrollProxy.minimumZoomScale
        scrollProxy.maximumZoomScale = 20.0
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView?) {
        print("scrollViewWillBeginZooming")
    }
    func scrollViewDidEndZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
        print("scrollViewDidEndZooming")
    }
    func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("scrollViewDidZoom")
    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return editor
    }

}
```

A few notes:

- LevelScrollView is a UIScrollView
- I removed a few things not pertaining to this issue, let me know if it would be helpful to see the entire thing.
- The viewForZoomingIn delegate function is being called, with a valid UIView returning (the LevelScrollView), but the other three are never called no matter what I do.

Because of these things zooming isn't working. How would I accomplish this successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: All zooming does is to scale-transform the zoomed view (`editor` in your example). It doesn't magically say, "oh, this is a scroll view, he actually wants me to zoom it _too_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I was able to find for this was to embed the entire scrollview in a separate UIView, and then enable zooming for that.